# ++ working in a strange way on URL

Tags: php

I am trying to produce the following urls however with the code below I am getting this why?

**Result:**

`$prev = http://domain.co.nz/pages/brand-02
 $next = http://domain.co.nz/pages/brand-02`

**What I am wanting:**

`$prev = http://domain.co.nz/pages/brand-01 - Should not be able to go any lower then 01
 $next = http://domain.co.nz/pages/brand-02`

**Code:**

```
<?php

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$pageSlug = $url;

$prev=$pageSlug--;
echo 'prev = ' .$prev. '<br/>';



echo 'next' . '<br/>' . '<br/>';

$next=$pageSlug++;

echo 'next = ' .$next. '<br/>';

echo '<a href="' .$next.'" > Next</a>';

?>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I get the correctly, you are trying to `++` and `--` on `string`?!

Comment: @Dekel Yup hence why I know it needs to be re written just not sure how

Comment: @Dekel, if you never met ++/-- for strings it doesnt mean such operations don't exist.

Comment: @Dekel It gives a syntax error however I would be expecting 00 or 0 but in my case its double int

Comment: If you get a syntax error this is a bit of a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with a string, you will need to extract the numerical part before incrementing or decrementing. Here is one way to do it:

```
<?php

$url = 'testing/.sad/05';

// get any numbers from end of string
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#(\d+)$#', $url, $matches)) {
    // if we have a match
    $page = $matches[1];
    $prev = substr_replace($url, sprintf('%02d', $page - 1), -strlen($page));
    $next = substr_replace($url, sprintf('%02d', $page + 1), -strlen($page));
} else {
    $prev = $next = null;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: How can I make it 01 etc instead of singular

Comment: @JessMcKenzie sorry, i fixed another mistake... it's working now

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to a manual you will see

> Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported.

That's why

```
$pageSlug--
```

has **no effect** and `$pageSlug` remains the same.

And though you can increment strings, code

```
$next = $pageSlug++;
```

means

> Assign `$pageSlug` to `$next` and **then** increment `$pageSlug`.

That's why both of your operations do not work.

Comment: I see now that I need to increment the `$next` and I have done this were it is called within the links, however I am still not having any luck with the `$prev` still showing 02

Comment: Did you read what i've just quoted: `character variables can be incremented but not decremented`? Did you see word __not__?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") ."://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

//$pageSlug = $url;

$pageSlug = explode("code-",$url)[0];
$page = explode("code-",$url)[1];
$prev = $page--;
$prev=$pageSlug."code-".$page;
echo 'prev = ' .$prev. '<br/>';
echo 'next' . '<br/>' . '<br/>';
$next = page++;
$next=$pageSlug."code-".$next;
echo 'next = ' .$next. '<br/>';
echo '<a href="' .$next.'" > Next</a>';

?>
```